# When using p-dropdown in my formArray, the values ​disappear depending on the size of the box

Tags: css, angular, dropdown, primeng

I use the primeng p-dropdown in my code and I noticed that if it doesn't reach a height **X** (for example 4 clicks in add), the values ​​of the box disappear

[image]

if appendTo = "body" is added, the box remains fixed, which hinders the user's view, below I set up a cod on the stackblitz to simulate the conflict

**https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hkxswt**

Answer (score 0):

your css has `overflow-y: auto;`. remove it and dropdown won't be hidden by this container

Comment: this doesn’t solve it, because I need to scroll so it doesn’t hide 100% of the height of my screen appendTo body is a solution, but there is the problem of always rolling